# Package paperandpencil.sty disables page numbering, is there a way to reenable it?

Tags: page-numbering

I wrote a questionnaire with LaTeX using the package `paperandpencil.sty` (http://www.qdds.de/index.php?id=129). The package somehow disables page numbering, but I need the questionnaire to have those. Is there a way to enforce/reenable page numbering or to create my own that are similar to the standard numbering in the article-class?

Here is my preamble with a short example.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, top=10mm, bottom=20mm, left=10mm, right=10mm, headsep=10mm, footskip=12mm}
\usepackage[interviewer, nonumbers]{paperandpencil}
\setlength{\answerwidth}{\linewidth}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{page}{75}
\addtocounter{section}{7}
\section{Example Code}

\startbox
\begin{flushleft}
\textbf{This is an example.}
\end{flushleft}
\stopbox

\end{document}
```

My knowledge of LaTeX unfortunately does not cover the understanding of source code of packages, and the documentation of `paperandpencil.sty` does not cover page numbering. Considering that it is a package created by my german university, I presume none of you guys know it. I already disabled every unnecessary package but could not find any interactions. I would be glad if someone can point out my mistakes, or, if there are none, could come up with a solution how to manually insert page numbering into the document.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Sorry, I cleared up all the unnecessary parts of the preamble.

Comment: Your sample document doesn't compile.  (It could also be a lot more minimal.)

Comment: `! LaTeX Error: \thechapter undefined.` , `! LaTeX Error: Unknown option 'interviewer' for package 'paperandpencil'.` ...

Comment: your example can not possibly need `morefloats` or `color` or `csquotes` or most of the other packages there, please delete anything not needed _for the example_ and _add_ anything that is needed.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer there are two files of that name in the zip and this document generates errors with either,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Yes, my comment was the consequence of an misinterpretation, sorry about that

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. What they^ said. However, the style includes `\pagestyle{empty}` which kills page numbers. Try `\pagestyle{plain}` for numbers in the footer.

Comment: No need to apologize your comment mad e me look in the archive and see a second file, it just didn't help:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Not surprising: the two are identical. (According to `diff` and assuming you're talking about `paperandpencil.sty`.)

Comment: @cfr I did wonder about checking that but decided not:-)

Comment: I would like to know which packages you disabled as 'unnecessary' given what's left!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Quicker than compiling, especially since I didn't cut-paste the nMWE.

Comment: this is a totally unsubstantiated comment -- a wild guess.  the options for package `paperandpencil' include `nonumbers`.  i'd try removing that, and see what happens.  (there are lots of things that could be numbered of course, but pages are a pretty obvious possibility.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton That can't be it as there is no such option. At least `nonumbers` appears nowhere in the file or in any file which is part of the package.

Comment: @cfr -- i didn't look at anything but the posted example, which clearly has a line `\usepackage[interviewer, nonumbers]{paperandpencil}` so i'm not surprised if you're correct about the code or the documentation.  (other commenters said that the code doesn't run without errors, and one specifically says that `interviewer` is an unknown option ... but also that there are two files by the same name in the zip.  lots of room here for confusion.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Indeed. The two files are identical, though. If you run the MWE as is, it only complains about `interviewer`. If you remove that and solve some other problems, eventually it complains that `nonumbers` is not a known option, either. The MWE complicates things considerably!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a ***Minimal Working*** Example which reinstates page numbers and compiles without error.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage{paperandpencil}
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}
  \pagenumbering{arabic}
  \setcounter{page}{75}
  \addtocounter{section}{7}
  \section{Example Code}

  \begin{flushleft}
    \textbf{This is an example.}
  \end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

[image: page numbers with <code>plain</code> style]

## EDIT

Just some notes about this. The `.sty` file includes some questionable code. For example:

```
\renewcommand*\thechapter{\bf{\arabic{chapter}.}}
```

Not only does this require you to use a class which defines chapters (e.g. `book` or `report` but not `article), it is using a long-deprecated command to set the font weight or, more accurately, it is *misusing* a long-deprecated command.

`\bf` is a pre-LaTeX2e command. It never took an argument. That is, even if it was the right way to set bold, it should not be used like this.

Alternatives:

```
\renewcommand*\thechapter{\textbf{\arabic{chapter}.}}
```

or

```
\renewcommand*\thechapter{\bfseries\arabic{chapter}.}
```

But the problem with defining things this way is that you will get bold and a following dot if `\thechapter` is used in a cross-reference, for example, which may not be what you want. `\thechapter` should really set only the basic format of the counter i.e. arabic or Roman numerals or whatever. This is from the `book.cls`:

```
\renewcommand \thechapter {\@arabic\c@chapter}
```

It would be better if the package used this (if necessary) and handled the default format of `\chapter` appropriately.

The package does not, however, redefine `\thesection`. So when you combine it with the default `book.cls` definition:

```
\renewcommand \thesection {\thechapter.\@arabic\c@section}
```

you end up with not one dot, but two, between the chapter number and the section number (as shown in the output of my MWE). If you define a chapter (to avoid the zero thing, for example), you then get:

[image: poorly formatted chapter]

which does not look right to me at all.

Using this package without understanding the code is, I'm afraid, likely to be a frustrating experience. It is not at all careful, for example, to choose macro names which are likely not to conflict with those used by other packages. It does not, for example, use a prefix for internal commands, and it defines several two-letter macros (e.g. `\df`, `\km`) which is not good practice.

It may be intended, but the package also defines environments in a way which will add a lot of vertical spacing e.g. it uses `center` and `tabular` together, which will both add vertical spacing before and after their contents.

Comment: Thank you for the solution and the insight. When I insert my code into your minimal example and add the necessary packages, I get a working questionnaire with page numbering. I can't really grasp which option/package in my original code killed the page numbering, but right now the result is what matters.

Comment: @Leo.SurveyMeth `\pagestyle{plain}` is what is doing the work.